# Web app for taking high res screenshots of my app

Tags: screenshot

I have a web app, and I want to take a good screenshot of it, for its landing page.
This is an example. Anyone know how to do it, on on a macbook air
[Here is an example](https://a248.e.akamai.net/camo.github.com/66c30ccf45e02b46a64e1a3fc73bf812439ecbfc/687474703a2f2f7374726970652e6769746875622e636f6d2f616262612f73637265656e73686f742e706e67)

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I did not downvote, but you should make it ultra clear that you are looking for a webapp, not a desktop screenshot tool. I recommend you add a sentence describing how such a webapp could work, what input, what ouput. Also describe if you want a real screenshots (of a real browser really loading the page) or a mockup (embedding your image within the image of a browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use a computer app instead of a web app to take screenshot. [Here are some good screenshot application](http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/utilities-roundups/8-versatile-mac-screenshot-apps/) for Mac

Next you need to set your screen resolution to the highest possible resolution and it must take the screenshot in a pretty good resolution. Also check if there's some settings for the screenshot application regarding to the resolution of images.

#### Take the screenshot without any app

On Mac you can take screenshots without any additional app. See this to know how 
http://osxdaily.com/2010/05/13/print-screen-mac/

Then you can use the image on the clipboard to edit in an image editing software. Read this for a trick to get high resolution screenshots in photoshop 
http://www.turbophoto.com/Photoshop-Tricks/screenshot-photoshop-trick/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Some web apps that take screenshots of live website: [Browshot](http://browshot.com/) (real time), [Url2Png](http://url2png.com/)